# Find the number of positive integral solution to this expression

Tags: number-theory, real-numbers

$$
a+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{c}{3}=7 \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \right)
$$
Find the number of positive integral solution.

Comment: Looks like a linear Diophantine equation ...

Comment: Can be recast into
$$
6a + 3b + 2c = 77
$$

Comment: Lets go ahead and multiply both sides of the equation by six to clear out the frustrating fractions.  $6a+3b+2c = 77$.  Now is it clearer?  There are several techniques you could use at this point, e.g. generating functions.

Comment: Yes at this point it is clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Find the number of positive integral solution: $a+\frac{b}{2}+\frac{c}{3}=7 \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \right).$

As noted in the comments, it is equivalent to: $6a + 3b + 2c = 77$.

Consider mod 3 and mod 2:
$$\begin{align}2c\equiv2 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow &c\equiv 1 \pmod 3 \Rightarrow c=3m+1;\\
&b\equiv1 \pmod 2 \Rightarrow b=2n+1.\end{align}$$
Substitute these into the original equation:
$$6a+3(2n+1)+2(3m+1)=77 \Rightarrow 6(a+n+m)=72 \Rightarrow a=12-m-n.$$
Hence:
$$\begin{cases}a=12-m-n>0\\b=2n+1>0\\
c=3m+1>0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}m+n<12\\n>-\frac12\\
m>-\frac13\end{cases} \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{12}k=78.$$
Indeed, when $m=0 \Rightarrow 0\le n\le 11 \Rightarrow 12$.

Here are the solutions:
$$\begin{align}(a,b,c)&=(12,1,1) \Rightarrow 1;\\
&=(11,1,4),(11,3,1) \Rightarrow 2;\\
&=(10,1,7),(10,3,4), (10,5,1) \Rightarrow 3;\\
&\ \ \ \vdots \\
&=(1,1,34),(1,3,31),\cdots , (1,23,1) \Rightarrow 12 \\ \\
&\text{So, it is:} \ 1+2+3+\cdots +12=78.\end{align}$$

Comment: Sir $$6(a+n+m)=72 mean a+n+m=12 since a greater than zero so "a" range 1 to 12, but m,n due to substitution will be zero also. So solutions=12+11...1=78??$$

Comment: Yes, $a$ ranges between $1$ and $12$ inclusive, but the number of solutions will be $11+10+\cdots +2+1=66$.

Comment: When a=1---> n+m=11 means 12 solutions starting from 12 then 11 and so on, since m,n can take zero as solution.

Comment: a+m+n=12  ,a range 1 to 12 and (m,n) 0 to 12 ,if we count solutions is 78, sir, please check,

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, there was a miscount, fixed it.

Comment: Yes,thank you sir,....

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this directly.We have 
$$11\le 6a+3b+2c=77\Rightarrow 1\le a\le 12$$

$$a=n\Rightarrow 3b+2c=77-6n=\text{ odd }$$

It follows that the number of possible values for $b$ is equal to the number of odds from $1$ to
$\lfloor {\frac{77-6n}{3}}\rfloor$.

Consequently there are $$1+2+3+\cdots 11=\frac{11\cdot 12}{2}=66\space\text{solutions}.$$

Comment: What you did to c when write (77-6n)/3  for b

Comment: You do have $2c=$ even.The floor function (integer part) has been used but you can use only words instead. Yo can solve this problem the same way for $2m+1$ instead of $77$. Try it !

Comment: Sir correct answer is 78.

Comment: Then my answer is wrong. I am sorry. I will try to see the error when I have a disposition that I do not have for now. I got tired of the downvotes without justification, some of which the bad intention and resentment is almost obvious. Maybe I'm wrong but that's my feeling: all downvote must be justified. Regards.